# Unable to run nunit tests from teamcity

Tags: testing, nunit, teamcity

I am having problems running Nunit tests from teamcity using Nunit build runner.

Until now these tests are run from a machine where the Teamcity and a build agent is hosted.And the tests run as expected on this machine. But we are moving the tests from this machine to another machine and when I try to run tests from this other machine I get the following error

```
[10:57:25]: 2012-08-01 10:57:25,688 [9052] ERROR JetBrains.BuildServer.NAntLoggers.NUnitLauncher2 - Compatible parser was not found
[10:57:25]: JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe #TeamCityImplicit
[10:57:25]: Arguments will be recieved implicitly
[10:57:25]: JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe @@ <xml-arguments-file>
[10:57:25]: JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe {v1.1|v2.0|mono-1.0|mono-2.0|ANY} {MSIL|x86|x64} Plugin{|Plugin...}
[10:57:25]: Plugin PartCover:
[10:57:25]: /partcover:<path to PartCover.exe> [/partcover-arg:<arg>]* [/partcover-arguments:<arguments line>] [/partcover-platform:<MSIL|x86|x64|NATIVE>@<v1.1|v2.0|ANY|NATIVE>] [/partcover-reg:true]
[10:57:25]: Where:
[10:57:25]: /partcover-arg: argument should be repeated for every argument of PartCover
[10:57:25]: /partcover-arguments: argument should be excaped to be passed to the program as one argument
[10:57:25]: Plugin mstest:
[10:57:25]: /mstestlocation:[ directory name ] /testcontainer:[ file name ] [/isolated] /runconfig:[ file name ]
[10:57:25]: Plugin dotCover:
[10:57:25]: /dotcover:<path to dotCover.exe> [/dotcover-platform:<MSIL|x86|x64|NATIVE>@<v1.1|v2.0|ANY|NATIVE>] [/dotcover-logs:<logs_folder>]
[10:57:25]: Plugin NCover:
[10:57:25]: /ncover:<path to NCover.Console.exe> [/ncover-arg:<arg>]* [/ncover-arguments:<arguments line>] [/ncover-platform:<MSIL|x86|x64|NATIVE>@<v1.1|v2.0|ANY|NATIVE>]
[10:57:25]: Where:
[10:57:25]: /ncover-arg: argument should be repeated for every argument of NCover
[10:57:25]: /ncover-arguments: argument should be excaped to be passed to the program as one argument
[10:57:25]: Plugin NUnit-*:
[10:57:25]: No assemblies were found.
[10:57:25]: No assemblies were found.
[10:57:25]: [/category-include:categories] [/category-exclude:categories] [/addin:addins] [/runAssemblies:processPerAssembly] <assembly>[(;| )<assembly>[...]]
[10:57:25]: Supported plugin names:
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.2.10
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.2.9-VSTS
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.2.9-VSTS-9.0
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.4.1
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.4.6
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.4.7
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.4.8
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.4.8-resharper
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.5.0
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.5.10
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.5.2
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.5.3
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.5.4
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.5.5
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.5.6
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.5.7
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.5.7-resharper
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.5.8
[10:57:25]: NUnit-2.5.9
[10:57:25]: 2012-08-01 10:57:25,712 [9052] ERROR JetBrains.BuildServer.NAntLoggers.NUnitLauncher2 - Failed to parse arguments
[10:57:25]: Process exited with code -1
```

The build agent that is running these tests is on one machine(say Machine-a) and the tests are on a different machine(Machine-b).So I am using the build agent on Machine-a to run tests on Machine-b and is throwing the above error. I am not sure if that is valid as the build agent is on a different machine.

I also have another build agent installed on Machine-c. So I tried running the nunits tests which are on Machine-c with the same machine's(Machine-c) build agent and get the following error.

```
[14:33:02]: 2012-08-01 14:33:02,755 [3116] ERROR JetBrains.BuildServer.NAntLoggers.NUnitLauncher2 - Failed to parse arguments
[14:33:02]: No assemblies were found.
[14:33:02]: Process exited with code -1
```

So I am confused as to if I am missing some nunit assemblies(which can be easily copied from another machine) on Machine-b,Machine-c or there is some other problem.

I also wonder if the Teamcity,build agent and nunit tests-all the 3 items should be on the same machine to run the tests successfully(as it is currently for us now).

Could someone please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Another reason you see this is if you've got the wrong version of the CLR set for your NUnit runner (e.g. 2.0 instead of 4.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the reason I was unable to run tests is that, I was trying to use a network share name to access the tests assembly.But Teamcity's NUnit build runner expects a path relative to its checkout/build directory or an absolute path, but not a path with network share name.